# Don't know how to prove that the matrix is normal an find

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that the matrix is normal
$$ A=(E-C)(E+C)^{-1}$$
where

E - identity matrix

C -  some matrix

and find its canonical form for 
$$ C=\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 1& -1\\
  -1& 0& 1\\
   1& -1& 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
I think, I will be able to  make the second point. But I don't know how to prove the first.

Comment: What are $E$ and $C?$

Comment: What are $E$ and $C$ supposed to be?

Comment: Maybe $E$ is a notation for $I$

Comment: This is a Cayley transform. In general $A$ is not normal. However, as it is a polynomial in $C$, it is normal when $C$ is normal.

Comment: The standard test for normality is to see if $A^*A = AA^*$. However for a general $C$ I don't tihnk this will work. For your choice of $C$ however, it will since that $C$ is normal